# Set post thumbnail as background image

Tags: php, wordpress

Sorry if I make any mistakes - quite new at codding...

I am creating a wordpress template and I am trying to get a specific post thumbnail to be the background of a DIV.

I looked through a few answer and thought that this could be the answer:

```
 <?php $post_id = 15;
    $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail( null, $size, $attr );
    ?>  

 <div style="background-image:url('<?php echo $thumbnail ?>')"> Hello World </div>
```

Unfortunately it did not work... :(

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

OK! Solved with this:

```
<?php $post_id = 15;
    $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is: `get_the_post_thumbnail()` function returns the post thumbnail image tag, see the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/).

You need to use:
either `the_post_thumbnail_url()` inside the loop;
or

```
$image_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ), 'thumbnail-size' );
$image_src = $image_array[0];
```

outside the loop.